# Allow anonymous upload for Vsftpd?

Tags: linux, ftp, upload, anonymous, vsftpd

I need a basic FTP server on Linux (CentOS 5.5) without any security measure, since the server and the clients are located on a test LAN, not connected to the rest of the network, which itself uses non-routable IP's behind a NAT firewall with no incoming access to FTP.

Some people recommend [Vsftpd](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/) over [PureFTPd](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd) or [ProFTPd](http://proftpd.org/). No matter what I try, I can't get it to allow an anonymous user (ie. logging as "ftp" or "anonymous" and typing any string as password) to upload a file:

```
# yum install vsftpd

# mkdir /var/ftp/pub/upload

# cat vsftpd.conf
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
xferlog_file=YES

#anonymous users are restricted (chrooted) to anon_root
#directory was created by root, hence owned by root.root
anon_root=/var/ftp/pub/incoming
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES

#chroot_local_user=NO
#chroot_list_enable=YES
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
chown_uploads=YES
```

When I log on from a client, here's what I get:

> 500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/var/ftp/pub/incoming

I also tried "# chmod 777 /var/ftp/incoming/", but get the same error.

Does someone know how to configure Vsftpd with minimum security?

Thank you.

---

Edit: SELinux is disabled and here are the file permissions:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux
SELINUX=disabled
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
SETLOCALDEFS=0

# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
# getenforce
Disabled

# grep ftp /etc/passwd
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin

# ll /var/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Mar 14 10:53 ftp

# ll /var/ftp/
drwxrwxrwx 2 ftp ftp 4096 Mar 14 10:53 incoming
drwxr-xr-x 3 ftp ftp 4096 Mar 14 11:29 pub
```

---

Edit: latest vsftpd.conf:

```
listen=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
xferlog_file=YES

#anonymous users are restricted (chrooted) to anon_root
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/var/ftp/pub/incoming
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES

#500 OOPS: bad bool value in config file for: chown_uploads
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=ftp
```

---

Edit: with trailing space removed from "chown_uploads", err 500 is solved, but anonymous still doesn't work:

```
client> ./ftp server
Connected to server.
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.5)
Name (server:root): ftp
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/var/ftp/pub/incoming
Login failed.
ftp> bye
```

With user "ftp" listed in /etc/passwd with home directory set to "/var/ftp" and access rights to /var/ftp set to "drwxr-xr-x" and /var/ftp/incoming to "drwxrwxrwx"...could it be due to PAM maybe? I don't find any FTP log file in /var/log to investigate.

---

Edit: Here's a working configuration to let ftp/anonymous connect and upload files to /var/ftp:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
```

Comment: with chown_uploads you should also set chown_username

Comment: Now, I'm getting "bad bool value in config file for: chown_uploads" :-/

Comment: look if there is some kind of non-visible character in the conf file

Comment: @user15318: The vsftpd.conf you have posted above works fine on a CentOS system I have to hand. Are there any relevant messages in /var/log/messages ?

Comment: Indeed, there was an extra space at the end. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ian: No, the user logs on successfully: CONNECT: Client "192.168.0.9" [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.0.9", anon password "test"

Comment: For me, the parameter `write_enable=YES` was missing. Reading your settings solved my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have created a dir called pub/**upload**:

```
# mkdir /var/ftp/pub/upload
```

But then you configured uploads to go to pub/**incoming**:

```
anon_root=/var/ftp/pub/incoming
```

So it's a simple path mismatch, all the rest seems OK.

Answer (score 1):

1. For anonymous logins, change the "ftp" users home directory in `/etc/passwd`.

   ```
   ftp:x:119:131:ftp daemon,,,:/var/ftp/pub/:/bin/false
   ```
2. And add this to your `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file.

   ```
   allow_writeable_chroot=YES
   ```
3. And make sure that the `ftp` user has access (`chmod 755`) to enter every directory up to the location `/var/ftp/pub/`

I was fighting this problem for hours. vsftpd doesn't give clear help or suggestions for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have SE linux enabled. Rather than disable the whole thing you can use

`/usr/sbin/setsebool -P ftp_home_dir 1`

to allow ftp to work correctly.

**EDIT**
Looking over this again, if the commands above are what you really typed then `/var/ftp/pub/incomming` doesn't exist so make sure it does then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but SELinux is disabled: # /usr/sbin/setsebool -P ftp_home_dir 1 : "setsebool:  SELinux is disabled."

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `userlist_deny=NO` in your conf file. Change it to `YES` and make sure that the username you're using isn't in `/etc/vsftpd/user_list` or in `/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers`.

Answer (score 0):

here is what worked for me (he said, while mentally strangling a developer)

vsftpd.conf:

```
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_root=/var/ftp/
```

create/chown Directories

```
mkdir /var/ftp
chown nobody:nogroup /var/ftp
mkdir /var/ftp/uploads
chown ftp:ftp /var/ftp/uploads
#edit for good measure also (gave me grief with pure-ftpd)
chmod 777 /var/ftp/uploads
```

change homedir in

```
/etc/passwd:

    ftp:x:116:124:ftp daemon,,,:/var/ftp:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

(default home dir on debian is /srv/ftp so you can make yo life 
easier sticking to that dir)

uploads are possible to /var/ftp/uploads
SElinux/Apparmor is disabled on this system, debian 10.3

**Note:** vsftp will throw an errormessage if the initial homedirectory
has rw rights (aka chown ftp:ftp) on /var/ftp directly

*Edit note: with the faint hope, this whole text is somewhat understandable.
Klaus*

Answer (score -1):

Is SE linux enabled. Folks in that forum were able to resolve the issue by disabling SE linux.

http://rackerhacker.com/2007/06/14/500-oops-error-from-vsftpd/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but still no go: SELinux is disabled, and the dir/file permissions seems OK. I edited the question.

Comment: Disabling SELinux is a bad idea, especially when it's blindly used to "solve" a problem with configuration.