# vsftpd allow anonymous log-in

Tags: centos, login, ftp

I'm setting up a ftp server, that will allow anonymous to READ/WRITE to the server. Here is my configuration.

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
xferlog_std_format=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=NO
tcp_wrappers=YES
no_anon_password=YES
```

In my `/var/ftp/` i set the permission to 755. When I tried to set it to 777 i got the following error, when i tried to log in.

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writeable anonymous root login failed.
```

Do i need to set up anything else to allow READ/WRITE for anonymous?

Comment: Read this discussion: http://serverfault.com/questions/247096/allow-anonymous-upload-for-vsftpd

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put 777 on /var/ftp. You must tell vsftpd where is your anonymous directory (anon_root directive), and then add:

```
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=ftp
```

to your configuration.
The 'ftp'username must exist in your /etc/passwd.

Comment: I was able to log-in. When i tried to mkdir. i am getting the 550 error. Suggestions?

Comment: Which is the exact message you get?

Comment: 550 create directory operation failed.

Comment: /var/ftp is owned by root, and 'ftp' cannot access it for write. Add a sub-directory in /var/ftp (i.e. 'pub'), change its ownership in 'ftp', change the default anon_root to '/var/ftp/pub' and try to create a directory in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the directory permissions -

`chgrp ftp ..path` and    `chown ftp ..path`