# Disable upload in vsftpd

Tags: linux, vsftpd

How can I prevent local users from uploading files in vsftpd? I know I can prevent them from downloading files by setting the string `download_enable` in vsftpd.conf on "NO", is there an option for uploading files too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's disabled by default. In fact, getting vsftpd to allow upload is rather tricky.

For example: [Allow anonymous upload for Vsftpd?](https://serverfault.com/questions/247096/allow-anonymous-upload-for-vsftpd)

To disable it you could do any of the following:

- `anon_upload_enable=NO`
- `write_enable=NO`
- Permissions on "incoming" set
  to disallow writes

Answer (score 0):

Find "write_enable=" in vsftpd.conf

Set it to "NO", so it should look like this:
write_enable=NO

Now restart vsftpd using this command:
service vsftpd restart

Comment: I'm not sure what this adds to Steve's earlier answer.

Comment: Haven't seen his answer. My answer adds "service vsftpd restart".

Comment: I think that's rather my point: you should read the extant answers to a question before adding one.